# Android Wear 2.0: Dismissable fullscreen ambient notifications

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

[ongoing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)) notifications in Android Wear 2.0 have an ambient full screen mode, so when going to ambient the notifications stay on the screen with the clock at the top, like so:

[image: Android Wear ongoing notification in ambient mode].

This is perfect for my app that display train departures because I have all the info I need on the screen when going to the train. The problem is that I can't dismiss the notification with swipe.

How do I get a notification that sticks to the screen in ambient mode and that I can swipe to dismiss like a normal notification?

Comment: You may want to check this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037952/Ambient-Mode-On-Demand-for-Android-Wear?msg=5143605) wherein same effect was accomplished using the OverlayView Class. By creating a blank first page - to the left of the Ambient Mode action - that hides the overlay when the user swipes to it. Besides the code you’ve already seen in `OverlayAdapter`, there are just a couple of other pieces required to make this work, and they go into a `setVisibility` method on `OverlayView`. See the given link for more information and sample codes. Hope that helps.